# Alloy Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ( Table )

Tags: javascript, titanium, tableview, titanium-alloy

Following on from http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/174047/how-to-update-a-tabbed-table

As I believe the alloy.js is fired BEFORE the UI I call my function like....

```
<Tab title="Event List" icon="KS_nav_views.png">
            <Window title="Event List" onFocus="showEventslist">
                <TableView id="eventslisttable" layout="vertical"></TableView>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
```

and then

```
$.eventslisttable.setData([]);
```

....how ever I get Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined which I assume is saying eventslisttable does not exist.

Do I need to have eventslisttable listed else where ?

Comment: *"which I assume is saying eventslisttable does not exist"* No, it means that `$` does not exist, just like the error message says.

Comment: Thanks for responding how ever I have been told "In Alloy, views etc are all referenced in controllers using $. as a prefix to the id of the object"

Comment: I don't know Alloy, I can only tell you what the error means.

Comment: Can you post whole code from your controller. You probably delete $ reference to controller object and this triggers an error.